# How to change OData API paths to lowercase format?

Tags: swagger, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, .net-5

I added OData to my .NET Web API. I only use it for querying data (HttpMethod GET).

When I run my application, and I look at Swagger I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, the OData endpoints use uppercase name for the resource set which I something I really dislike. It's important to note that the endpoints **work** **fine** even in lowercase.

How can I make it so that the OData endpoints use lowercase by default to create consistency in my swagger documentation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

In your startup.cs

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that easy. Thanks a lot.